# Is there any analyzer that performs exact word matching in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any analyzer that performs exact word matching in elastic search

Example if, i have words like "America" and "American" and "America's", if i searched for "America" i should get only first one.. With standard analyzer it gives all the three ones.

I want to make sure this only at query time. I don't want to make changes to existing index. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Set your mapping to `not_analyzed`

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

That will not do anything to your input string, but will still allow it to be searchable. Note, if you do this searching on "america" will not match "America" as there is a difference in case.

If you want to be able to match those, then you should try the [keyword](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) analyzer.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
        "mappings" : {
            "type1" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "field1" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "keyword" }
                }
            }
        }
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to worry about analyzer.. While querying use term and terms queries it Ll behave as you asked..